# How to store returned value in a component prop vue js

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have this component for media upload

```
<media-upload
        :ref="'cover_uploader'"
        :collection="'cover'"
        :url="'{{ route('admin.upload.media', $folder) }}'"
        :accepted-file-types="''"
        :max-number-of-files="5"
        :max-file-size-in-mb="100"
        :accepted-file-types="''"
></media-upload>
```

And that route `:url="'{{ route('admin.upload.media', $folder) }}'"` triggers to the controller and that controller returns a json value after performing some logic.

```
public function uploadMedia(Request $request, $folder="uploads")
{
    if ($request->file('file')) {
        $media = MediaUploaderFacade::fromSource($request->file('file'))
                ->toDirectory($folder)
                ->upload();

        return response()->json($media);
    }
    return response()->json( 'Incorrect file', 422);
}
```

I want to store that `$media` which is comming from the controller in my component for performing other actions like this .

```
<media-upload
        :jsonHandler="jsonData(// I want to get that $media in here as a parameter)"
        :ref="'cover_uploader'"
        :collection="'cover'"
        :url="'{{ route('admin.upload.media', $folder) }}'"
        :accepted-file-types="''"
        :max-number-of-files="5"
        :max-file-size-in-mb="100"
        :accepted-file-types="''"
></media-upload>
```

Comment: Do you have access to media-upload or is it a 3rd party component

Comment: It is a third party component @RaduDiță

Answer (score 0):

I would create a method that makes the API request, and store response, something like:

`async uploadMedia(){
const {data} = await makeAPICallToUploadMedia();
this.media= data;
}`

then simply in media-upload element :jsonHandler='media'

Comment: The Media-upload component is third party component so where should I place that method ?

Comment: inside the component which you have the media element inside